# Java Buttons not being displayed?

Tags: java, android

I am using the code below and I have a button that is not being displayed. I think it has something to do with "SetContentView" because if I remove one of them the button will show up. I am not sure how to get around this so that everything shows up? Thanks!

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. 
 * @return */



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button OffWifi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.offwifi);
    OffWifi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
      public void onClick(View v) {                 
          WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);          
          }        
      });



    TextView tv = new TextView(this);       
    TextView status = new TextView(this);                  


    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();  
    wc.SSID = "\"Test\""; //IMP! This should be in Quotes!! 

    wc.hiddenSSID = true; 
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;      
    wc.priority = 10; 
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK); 
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);  
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA); 
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN); 
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED); 
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP); 
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP); 
    wc.preSharedKey = "\"Password\""; 
    WifiManager  wifiManag = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE); 
    boolean res1 = wifiManag.setWifiEnabled(true); 
    int res = wifi.addNetwork(checkPreviousConfiguration(wc)); 
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res ); 
    boolean es = wifi.saveConfiguration(); 
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "saveConfiguration returned " + es ); 
    boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);    
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );   

    tv.setText("You are now connected!  " +
            "Version 1.1");

    status.setText("The was an error connecting, please try again.");

       //@Override

    try {

        Thread.sleep(5000);

         ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 

         if (connec != null && (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)){  
                //You are connected, do something online. 
                setContentView(tv);

            }else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ) {              
                //Not connected.         
               setContentView(status);
            }  

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





}

public WifiConfiguration checkPreviousConfiguration(WifiConfiguration wc) {
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
 List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();     
    for(WifiConfiguration config : configs) {         
        if(config.SSID.equals(wc.SSID)) return config;     
        }     
    return wc; 
    } 

}
```

Main XML File

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:layout_width="246dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<Button
android:id="@+id/offwifi"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Turn Wifi Off" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setContentView() doesn't add views to the display, it replaces them. That's why your button is going away.

Use the existing tv in your XML layout instead of creating a new one, and only call setContentReview() once.

Like this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button OffWifi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.offwifi);
OffWifi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
  public void onClick(View v) {                 
      WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);          
      }        
  });


// remove these lines
// TextView tv = new TextView(this);       
// TextView status = new TextView(this);                  

// add this line
TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);


WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
WifiConfiguration wc....

 ect.ect. 

Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );   

// let's do this later
//tv.setText("You are now connected!  " +
//        "Version 1.1");

//status.setText("The was an error connecting, please try again.");

   //@Override

try {

    Thread.sleep(5000);

     ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 

     if (connec != null && (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)){  

            //You are connected, do something online. 

            // setting the ContentView replaces everything, so don't do that
            //setContentView(tv);

            tv.setText("You are now connected!  " +
               "Version 1.1");



        }else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ) {              
            //Not connected.         


           //setContentView(status);
           tv.setText("The was an error connecting, please try again.");
        }  

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You start your activity, setting its content view to something that has at least a button in. Then you create new instances of TextViews. Then later in OnCreate, you set the content view to one of the text views. If you are connected, the view is replaced with the TextView, and if you are not connected, the view is replaced with a TextView. If you remove one of the extra set content calls, you will see the button depending on whether you are connected or not.

This behaviour could be what you want, or what you might be wanting to do is add the TextViews to the layout, and get a handle to them the same way you have got a handle on the button, with FindViewById. You can then avoid everything in the try block because the textviews will already have been updated with new text. What your code currently does is replace the entire layout with a text view.

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the root object in your main.xml layout file, i.e.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById( R.id.linearlayout1 );
```

then you can add to that layout (it may not have been named linearlayout1) with

```
layout.addView ( status );
```

Comment: This is what is in my xml file. So do I add another linearlayout?

Comment: you just need to use an if-else statement to set your TextView text. Instead of making two new TextViews, make one with `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewbyId( R.id.tv );, then use your if -else in your try block and just set the text there.